# Starting SideKiq with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, rubber

We followed following steps that we found online to setup Rails env on EC2 using Rubber. The Rails server and Monit are working well however sidekiq workers are not getting switched on. Can someone please assist? Thank you in advance.

=== What we have done ===

```
$ rubber vulcanize sidekiq
$ ALIAS=mach1 ROLES=app,sidekiq,monit,web_tools cap rubber:create
$ cap rubber:bootstrap
$ cap deploy
```

//Rails Server is on and working well now

```
$ cap rubber:sidekiq:start
  * 2014-07-11 09:46:55 executing `rubber:init'
 ** Auto role: app => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: unicorn => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: nginx => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: sidekiq => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: monit => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: web_tools => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: db => mach1.m.com, {:primary=>true, :platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: postgresql => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: postgresql_master => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
 ** Auto role: collectd => mach1.m.com, {:platform=>"linux", :provider=>"aws"}
  * 2014-07-11 09:46:57 executing `rubber:sidekiq:start'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' -H -u ubuntu bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/projectrepo-production/current ; nohup bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C /mnt/projectrepo-production/current/config/sidekiq.yml -P /mnt/projectrepo-production/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid >> /mnt/projectrepo-production/current/log/sidekiq.log 2>&1 &'"
    servers: ["mach1.m.com"]
    [mach1.m.com] executing command
    command finished in 808ms
$
```

SideKiq Log says

```
!!! ERROR HANDLER THREW AN ERROR !!!
2014-07-11T04:30:40Z 22691 TID-oryg4a6cc ERROR: undefined method `user' for "Manager#processor_died died":String
2014-07-11T04:30:40Z 22691 TID-oryg4a6cc ERROR: /mnt/datahub_rubber-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/raven-ruby-776c042695dd/lib/raven/event.rb:50:in `initialize'
```